# Comparing Fields between docs in a Solr Query

Tags: solr

A solar query returns docs containing following fields as output:
field_1,field_2,field_3.
I want to compute difference between field_2 of different documents. What is the solar query for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare the fields of two different documents, that has to be done on the client side or at index time (which may not be feasible given the large of the documents)